# Add encrypted database to elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

You can add an RDS instance to an Elastic Beanstalk environment, but there is no option when you do this to have the RDS instance be encrypted.  You can modify the RDS instance after it's launched, but you can't modify whether or not it's encrypted.

The amazon docs discuss creating an independent RDS instance and modifying security groups but this seems antithetical to Elastic Beanstalk.

Is there a way to get an encrypted RDS instance that is attached to an Elastic Beanstalk environment?

Answer (score 5):

I **do not recommend** to create RDS instances from EB configuration panel. For most of the cases that may happen on your setup, it may won't be an issue, but when it comes to serious production setup, it may become a serious problem. RDS instances created from EB config panel are kind of merged to EB environment they were created in. **It means that every time you delete your environment, system forces you to remove RDS instance as well**. And that's not the way you want it to be, as environment should be the part you're not afraid to delete at any time.

Let's say you want to update your Multicontainer Docker setup, because there's an update going on. You would just clone current environment, then switch url and you're done. With RDS instances created as described above, you simply can't.

My advise is to create separate RDS instance, then add specific security group for this instance, and finally, add this security group in Configuration -> Instances -> EC2 security groups for EB environment, so it have access there. With that you can create encrypted instance of database and you can easily switch environment with no risk your database will be thrown away.
And if you're ok with standard environment variables for RDS, like RDS_DB_NAME etc. you can add the same in Configuration -> Software Configuration -> Environment Properties. That's how we do this for each production and serious server we're taking care of at work.

Comment: I agree with your answer completely. Just one note: In AWS the abbreviation EBS is for Elastic Block Store, not Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: Oh, you're right. Don't know where this habbit come from. ;-)

Comment: This kind of manual configuration is completely antithetical to the environment portability and automatic setup of elastic beanstalk.  The default configuration for an elastic beanstalk environment is to save a snapshot of the database upon deletion, and you get a giant warning when disabling this setting.

Comment: I don't know how you would create another beanstalk environment, but I do this with terraform, so there is no manual step for me than just `terraform run`. 
And what if you're hosting your production there? Would you do a deletion with snapshot and then create another one environment with such? That's not the desired portability and your client would not agree on that definitely. You still should separate your application environment setup from database. And that's the way I worked out with the steps described above. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  There is currently the following workaround:

1. Create a new encrypted RDS instance
2. Take a snapshot of this instance
3. Add an RDS instance to your Elastic Beanstalk environment based on this snapshot.  The snapshot is encrypted, and thus the database created based on it is encrypted as well